# css classes and a:hover

Tags: css

I need to assign css that will get "Dusty Arlia" not to underline.

```
    <p>
        <span class="published">
            By: <a href="http://whiterootmedia.com">Dusty Arlia</a><br />
            Published on December 19, 2011<br />
            Updated on January 26, 2012
        </span>
    </p>
```

I tried using CSS

```
    span.published a:hover {text-decoration:none;}
```

but that didn't work, so I tried

```
    .published a:hover {text-decoration:none;}
```

...and more. The CSS is in an external style sheet. I have placed these lines of CSS at the bottom and top of the stylesheet (I think it's at the bottom of the CSS page that gets rendered last). Anyways there is no CSS for the "published" class, but I do have CSS to underline my hyperlinks. I would like the hyperlink for my name not to have an underline. I CAN'T edit my HTML. I have hundreds of pages with this layout. I know I could possible do a "replace all" function if I have to edit the html, but I would like a CSS fix.

Comment: probably need more information as i could not reproduce this issue. Have you properly referenced the css?

Comment: Why do you have the `:hover` there.  With that there the style will only take effect when the mouse is over the link.

Answer (score 1):

if you think the css declaration is being overridden by another stylesheet, you can try saying `!important` at the end of it, which would override that other style (if it itself didn't already have `!important`)

```
span.published a:hover {text-decoration:none !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your css should work as defined unless some other generic selector is redefining it. Try this:

```
span.published a:hover {text-decoration:none !important;}
```

Comment: yeah posted same time. sorry. i'll +

Comment: This worked! YOU THE MAN! I never even seen the !important. How did this fix it again?

Comment: !important takes priority when declarations overwrite themselves. Since css by name definition cascades, if some other style overwrites your ".published a:hover" ... like "a:hover" which is ambiguous and therefore applies to ALL a tags, it will either overwrite or be overwritten depending on its placement in the sheet. They are successive, so if you put "a:hover" AFTER ".published a:hover" then it will be overwritten unless you add !important to the first one to let the css know to ignore redefining the element in question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've got some CSS somewhere that's taking precedence over the bit you're adding. If you've got Chrome you can use developer tools to look at all the rules affecting a particular element (right click -> inspect element, look under "Matched CSS rules"). You can do similar with Firebug in Firefox. This should give you the insight you need to fix the problem.

When all else fails, `!important` can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that your a:hover rules are not applied, because your other a selectors have more weight (specifity) and therefore overwrite your a:hover selector.

Eric Meyer has a great article on that subject: http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/link-specificity.html

First of all, make sure your a: selectors have the following recommended order:

1. A:link
2. A:visited
3. A:hover
4. A:active

To remember this order I always use the LoVe/HAte mnemonic.

By the way, the :hover pseudo class only applies to links which are in hover state (i.e. the mouse is over). Did you also specify the no-underline rules for a:link or a?

If none of that helps you might also try the !important directive. However this should not be necessary at all, but it might help you to figure out where the fault lies.